# Display webpart side to side on DispForm / EditForm

Tags: client-side-rendering, edit-form, display-form, layouts

I have edited my disp and edit form from a list to display a second webpart inside (parent-child list) and they are, as usual, displayed one above the other.

**I would like to have them side by side.**

On forms, there is no layout to allow this and I cannot have access to SharePoint Designer (I have visual studio though).

So does any of you know how to achieve this? (JS, CSR, via Visual Studio...)